# Best way to check jQuery POST method parameters for reducing jsp prepared statement query extra function

Tags: html, jsp, jdbc, jquery-form-validator

How can I make Submit TRUE result I mean from 2 INPUT field how to POST only one field of value to same JSP page like

```
<% string param=req.......
```

The most important thing is my PreparedStatement of jdbc have to be written twice for reason of two fields ... for checking Oracle DB of EMPLOYEE NO || NAME

By using Name field it's working fine and after changing of code by using Number it's working fine but I want you to help me is there any good way to code this stuff

**this is HTML Form**

```
 <form id="contact" method="get">
             <b>Employee No: </b> <input type="text" id="contact_number" size="15" name="number"/>
         &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <b>Employee Name:</b> <input type="text" id="contact_name" size="25" name="name"/>  
                 &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
```

This is validation jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact").submit(function() {
        if (($('#contact_number').val().length !== 0) && ($('#contact_name').val().length !== 0)) {
            return false;
        } else if (($('#contact_number').val().length === 0) && ($('#contact_name').val().length === 0)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

This is complete JSP & String sql="Oracle query" & JDBC

```
<%String number = request.getParameter("number");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
if (name != null) { %>
    <h3 id="myDiv"> Search results for  <i> <%= name %> </i> </h3>
<% }
else { %>
    <h4> Enter any Information on above field ... </h4>
<% } %>
<br>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
String sql="SELECT * FROM RWEMP WHERE ENAME= ?";
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hari","root");
PreparedStatement stat=con.prepareStatement(sql);
stat.setString(1,name);
ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery();
try {
    if(rs!=null) {
        %>
        <table class="gridtable" border=1 cellspan=60 cellpadding=16>
        <tr>
        <th> Emp ID </th>
        <th> Emp Name </th>
        <th> Emp Dept </th>
        <th> Emp D.o.B </th>
        <th> Show Record </th>
        <th> Record Update </th>
        <th> Compassionate </th>
        </tr>
        <%
        while(rs.next()) {
            %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= rs.getString("EID")%> </td>
            <td><%= rs.getString("ENAME") %> </td>
            <td><%= rs.getString("EDEPT")%> </td>
            <td><%= rs.getString("EDOB")%> </td>
            <td><input class="ui-button" type="button" onSubmit="result.jsp" target="destination" value="Show"></td>
            <td><input class="ui-button" type="button" onclick="update.jsp" target="destination" value="update"></td>
            <td><input class="ui-button" type="button" onclick="compassionate.jsp" target="destination" value="Compassionate"></td>
            </tr>
            <%
        }
    }
}
catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
con.close();
%>
</table>
```

For more Viewing Look at this [Fiddle's](http://jsfiddle.net/hari007/0t8wukrg/8/) HTML output only

Comment: please explain point 1 a bit more its unclear why you want to post only 1 value?

Comment: Employee Number [   ]    &  Employee name [  ]  ... is >> Form <<  &&  if user Enters Value of any one field ... it is okay .. 

 i have a Query for DB search in only one coloum filed search ...  so i want to get " HTML FORM RESULT (  of only one value ) " ..  

if  user enters two FORM FIELDS VALUES .. form wont send any thing ...

Comment: i want to make sure to send only one result to JSP page .. which is  either from ** NUMBER ** <input>  or ** Name ** <input>

Comment: so why dont you just put a restriction on form submit to enter only one field

Comment: yes i did ... and  that  " only one field option is working " ..User had a Choice of Searching by  NUMBER  or NAME...  so if he enters Number .. the REAL PROBLEM COMES OUT .. i don't know how to test in best way .. i just did by Considering *** 2 request.getparament()'s *** .. and again checking in JSP ...  it looks like that was odd .. so i want best way

Comment: for that put a dropdown which say select the criteria of search in your case is number and name and then provide him with a input field so when you submit form you have both columname and data to the next page

Answer (score 1):

> How can i make Submit TRUE result ... i mean from 2 INPUT field .. how
>   to POST only one Field of Value to same JSP page ... like :- <% string
>   param=req.......

To do that put a dropdown which say select the criteria of search in your case is number and name and then provide him with a input field so when you submit form you have both columname and data to the next page and you dont have write 2 queries.Form should be like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/jo2156w7/)

> If possible help me that if user Click on Particular userS table row
>   ... how to SEND that user row details to others jsp page ... for
>   complete record viewing or record editing purpose

Solution :Pass id of that row to other page

Create a column on each row name say Detail and do

```
<a href="/detailed.jsp?user_id="<%=user_id%>>Detail</a>
```

On detailed.jsp get value of user_id from get parameter and the apply the query with user_id to get all the details of that row